# Convert std::wstring to a unsigned char using std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

How I can force std::wstring to convert string to unsigned char (byte) using std::stringstream? Should be simple but below is not accepted by compiler (C++17):

```
int main()
{
    std::basic_string<wchar_t> s = L"123";
    std::basic_istringstream<wchar_t> iss(s);
    unsigned char number;
    iss >> number;  // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

The full error is :
"Error  C2678   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left - hand operand of type 'std::basic_istringstream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

I need to use this conversion in template functions together with other numerical types (int, float...) and don't want to make specialization or use different convert functions in this case only (like atoi).

Comment: In C, wchar_t is a typedef of an integral type. I guess that won't be a problem if you set:
unsigned int number;

Comment: `unsigned int temp; iss >> temp; numer = static_cast<unsigned char>(temp);` I assume you want to end up with `number == 123`, and not say `number == '1'`

Comment: `wchar_t` is typically 16 or 32 bits, `unsigned char` is typically 8 bits - what do you plan to do with the extra bits ?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to end with 123. I wondered is there some flag for this. unsigned int  is not good for me because I want to put this in template and have one convert function for all numerical types, like float or int64?

Comment: There are two errors. (1) Narrow `char` is not compatible with wide character streams. (2) A (wide or narrow) character operand to iostreams `>>` extracts a single formatted character, not a number. If you need to read a number, read some other numeric type like `int` and then convert it to your target type.

Comment: Your template would have to have a special case for `char` (and its flavors) and `wchar_t`. At least `unsigned char` fails to compile, giving you a heads-up. With `wchar_t` it'd be worse: `wchar_t number; iss >> number;` will compile and silently do something different than what you seem to expect (namely, you'd end up with `number == '1'`, not `number == 123`).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will explain further why this conversion to unsigned int, that seems not a big issue may be a problem if someone decides to write generic convert functions based on std streams. I think that it is a miss in std, there must be option unsigned char and also std::int8_t to be treated as integral types by stringstream . It also is bad design in std that std::int16_t is treated by stringstream<wchar_t> differently than std::int8_t by stringstream<char>.

Comment: `iostreams` is not an ideal design, but I predict that it is not going to change significantly in the foreseeable future. Arithmetic extractors are defined for the fixed list of types listed in the standard, and not for other arithmetic types (e.g. `char` and `wchar_t`). It is easy to work around this so it is not a serious limitation.